# Please help me in Teradata query, I need to add the same logic in my existing code

Tags: teradata

My table is this

```
CUSTOMER   DATE    speed  TV   NOVOUCHER
12      11/11/2021   1     0     0
12      11/11/2021   0     0     1
12      10/11/2021   0     1     0
12      10/11/2021   0     0     1
```

How can I achieve this-

```
PACKAGE     CUSTOMER    DATE        COUNT
SPEED ONLY     12      11/11/2021    1
TV ONLY        12      11/11/2021    0
SPEED+TV       12      11/11/2021    0
NO VOUCHER     12      11/11/2021    1
SPEED ONLY     12      10/11/2021    0
TV ONLY        12      10/11/2021    1
SPEED+TV       12      10/11/2021    0
NO VOUCHER     12      10/11/2021    1
```

Comment: So you want 4 copies of every `customer, date` combination, one with each of the four `package` values and a column with 0 or 1? If so, you could write 4 queries - one for each package, with the appropriate `CASE` to generate the 0/1 column - and `UNION ALL` the results.

Answer (score 0):

[This guide](https://dbmstutorials.com/random_teradata/teradata_transpose_column_to_rows.html) shows a couple of ways to transpose the data. However, its made slightly more complicated by the fact there isn't a single row for CUSTOMER and DATE (i.e. each customer has two rows of data for each date). Below is an example snippet of code using the UNPIVOT Teradata function that will give you the desired output.

```
SELECT * FROM TD_UNPIVOT(
ON
(SELECT
CUSTOMER,
"DATE", 
Sum(SPEED) AS SPEED,
Sum(TV) AS TV,
Sum(NOVOUCHER) AS NOVOUCHER,
CASE
    WHEN Sum(SPEED) = 1 AND Sum(TV) = 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS "SPEED+TV"
FROM table_name
GROUP BY CUSTOMER, "DATE"
)
USING
VALUE_COLUMNS('Package')
UNPIVOT_COLUMN('Count')
COLUMN_LIST('SPEED', 'TV', 'NOVOUCHER','SPEED+TV')
COLUMN_ALIAS_LIST('SPEED', 'TV', 'NOVOUCHER','SPEED+TV')
)X;
```

Worth noting the the UNPVIOT function is only available in certain version of Teradata (16 onwards I think)